# Check string presence in multiple cols and give output to separate cols in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, split, multiple-columns

I have dataframe as like follows:

```
    col1  col2  col3  col4
0   a-I    -     -    12.4
1   -      a-I   -    2.6
2   a-I    -     a-I  23
3   -      a-I   a-I  4
4   -      -     a-I  5
5   a-I    a-I   -    6.245
6   -      a     a    7.23
7   a      a     -    8
```

What I want is to check for `I` in each column if it is present than make `res` column with splitting string with `-`. Can anybody have any idea how to do this?

Expected Result would be like this:

```
    col1  col2  col3  col4 res
0   a-I    -     -    12.4  I 
1   -      a-I   -    2.6   I
2   a-I    -     a-I  23    I
3   -      a-I   a-I  4     I
4   -      -     a-I  5     I
5   a-I    a-I   -    6.245 I
6   -      a     a    7.23  -
7   a      a     -    8     -
```

Comment: What would your `res` column look like for that example?

Comment: Please provide the desired output

Comment: Have updated the Question.

Comment: @abhi1610 Okay good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Setup***

If you have other datatypes besides `str` in your DataFrame, you will need to replace all mentions of `df` with `df.astype(str)`.

#### Using `numpy.where` and `str.contains`

```
df.assign(res=np.where(df.sum(1).str.contains('I'), 'I', '-'))
```

#### Using a list comprehension:

List comprehensions are often faster than builtin `pandas` string methods:

```
df.assign(res=['I' if 'I' in row else '-' for row in df.values.sum(1)])
```

---

Both produce:

```
 col1 col2 col3 res
0  a-I    -    -   I
1    -  a-I    -   I
2  a-I    -  a-I   I
3    -  a-I  a-I   I
4    -    -  a-I   I
5  a-I  a-I    -   I
6    -    a    a   -
7    a    a    -   -
```

---

***Timings***

```
df = pd.concat([df]*5000)

%timeit ['I' if 'I' in row else '-' for row in df.values.sum(1)]
9.29 ms ± 310 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit np.where(df.sum(1).str.contains('I'), 'I', '-')
69.4 ms ± 2.17 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit df.sum(1).str.contains('I').map({False:'-',True:'I'})
83 ms ± 12.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: This returns the dataframe with the new column, but leaves df untouched. To change df directly, one could write `df['res'] = np.where(df.sum(1).str.contains('I'), 'I', '-')`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But, what If there is another type than `str`?

Comment: @abhi1610 Do `df.astype(str)`

Comment: Then just index the dataframe using only the string columns

Comment: Using `map` adds unecessary overhead for binary options often times, especially when `np.where` is available

Comment: @user3483203 list comprehension is not working with `int`.

Comment: @abhi1610 then replace `df.values` with `df.values.astype(str)`

Comment: @user3483203 i thinnk we can use `df.astype(str).values` instead as `df.values.astype(str)` in list comprehension gives me `TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type`

Comment: Ah, I wasn't testing with multiple types.  That should work.

Answer (score 1):

OR:

```
df['res']=df.sum(1).str.contains('I').map({False:'-',True:'I'})
print(df)
```

If it the pandas data frame contains types other than strings, do:

```
df['res']=df.astype(str).sum(1).str.contains('I').map({False:'-',True:'I'})
print(df)
```